# How do read / write barriers really get applied to garbage-collected code?

Tags: garbage-collection, virtual-machine

I'm confused about how Read / Write barriers are defined in the garbage collector literature. My understanding is that they about instrumenting reads and writes (so, in lower-level terms, reads and stores) happening in mutator threads. Another way of stating this is that these are bits of code that are injected before Loads/Stores. So far so good.

But then I look at examples such as of this article:

[image]

([shenandoah-gc-in-jdk-13-part-1-load-reference-barriers/](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/06/27/shenandoah-gc-in-jdk-13-part-1-load-reference-barriers/))

My interpretation of where barriers would have been put would have been something along the lines of:

```
void example(Foo foo) {
  Bar b1 = RB(RB(foo).bar);
  while (..) {
    Baz baz = RB(RB(b1).baz);
    WB(RB(b1), RB(makeSomeValue(baz)));
  }
}
```

That is, every time a reference is read, a read barrier would be put, and every time a write is performed, a write barrier is put. But I must obviously be wrong, so, what is it I am getting wrong?

I can see that in articles such as [The Locality of Concurrent Write Barriers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221032839_The_Locality_of_Concurrent_Write_Barriers) they also refer the barriers as operating on expressions of the type `o.f = p` (". Depending on policy, the barrier may notice either the insertion of the new pointer p into o or the deletion of the old pointer o.f."), as if they would only ever be applied to fields of objects, and not to generic assignments of the kind of `x = y`, as I would expect.

Comment: “as if they would only ever be applied to fields of objects”—well, static fields and array elements too. Or in other words, they do not apply to modifications of local variables.

Comment: I am not sure this counts as an answer, but doing `Bar b1 = RB(RB(foo).bar);` for example, is futile. This: `RB(foo)` will already establish a correct `foo`, be that in the "from-space" or "to-space", so the second read-barrier around `bar` makes no sense, as the previous one has already made sure `foo` is accurate.